# Change background color used in Recents apps screen with Flutter app

Tags: flutter

How can I change the color shown in the app switcher of Android. Right now the color comes up with a gray background, but I want it to be red.

[image: Gray image]

This is the app code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.red,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Material(
        child: Text('Check color in app switcher.'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `color` parameter of `MaterialApp` has no effect.

Comment: do you mean when the background of the x button?

Comment: I mean the whole bar behind the text is gray

Comment: Which Android version is that?

Comment: Android 5.1 Lollipop

Comment: Did you try running app in different emulators/devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the `MaterialApp` you would use the `color` attribute to change the color of the app bar in the switcher.

You could also use the `SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription` method which you would find in `package:flutter/services.dart`

Comment: I have already set `color` in `MaterialApp` but it doesn't affect the switcher color in Android 5.1

Comment: Tested now, and i see this is the case even now on my newer apps. Maybe there is a regression somewhere.

Comment: Seems to be a regression because app bar had a color with earlier version of Flutter.